# NameError: name 'menu' is not defined

Tags: python

A quien me pueda ayudar se lo agradecería, soy muy nuevo en esto. Estoy intentando llamar al método menu() de la clase Coche() y me aparece el error NameError: name 'menu' is not defined. se que podría ser. Agradezco su ayuda. El codigo es:

```
mLista=[]
class Coche():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__largoChazis=250
        self.__anchoChazis=120
        self.__ruedas=4
        self.__enmarcha=False
        self.__color="Blanco"

    def menu():
        ciclo=True
        while ciclo:
            opcion=int(input(("1 = Coche Nuevo !! 2 = Color !! 3 = mantenimiento !! 4 = Arrancar !! 5= Lista !! 6 = Estado !! 0 = Salir ")))
            if opcion==0:
                break
            elif opcion==1:
                entra='coche'
                entra=Coche()
                entra.cocheNuevo()
            elif opcion==5:
                break
    def cocheNuevo(self):
        ciclo = True
        while (ciclo):
            if not mLista: 
                mLista.append('miCoche1')
            else:
                numero=(len(mLista)+1)
                nuevo='miCoche'+str(numero)
                print (nuevo)
                nuevo=Coche()
                mLista.append(nuevo)
                #print (mLista[:])
                salir= int(input("Desea Agregar otro coche? 1- <si> 2-<no>: "))
                if salir == 2:
                    ciclo=False
                    break
    def arrancar(self):
        self.enmarcha=True

        if (self.enmarcha):
            cheq=self.chequeo()

    def estado(self):
        if (self.__enmarcha):
            print ("El coche esta en marcha")
        else:
            print ("El coche esta detenido")
    def c_color(self,algusto):
        self.__color=algusto
    def situacion(self,nombre):
        if self.__enmarcha:
            estado_2=" En marcha"
        else:
            estado_2=" Detenido"

        print ("El coche: ",nombre," tiene ", self.__ruedas," ruedas. Un ancho:",self.__anchoChazis,"  un largo: ",
            self.__largoChazis," Su color es: ",self.__color," Y su estado es: ",estado_2)
    def chequeo(self):
        print ("REALIZANDO CHEQUEO")
        self.gasolina="ok"
        self.aceite="ok"
        self.puertas="cerradas"

        if(self.gasolina=="ok" and self.aceite=="ok"and self.puertas=="cerradas"):
            return True
        else:
            return  False

menu()
```

Comment: Ya que ese método pertenece a la clase, tienes que llamarle con `Coche.menu()`. Y convendría que pusieras delante de ese método el decorador `@staticmethod`, para indicar que no opera sobre un coche en particular (no requiere el parámetro `self`), sino que es de la clase. De hecho, ya que ese menú no es algo específico de un coche, quizás tampoco debería formar parte de la clase `Coche`, sino ser un método aparte.

Comment: Agradecido por tu pronta respuesta. Ese era el problema. Gracias..